# Proof of $\limsup s_n = \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sup \{s_n: n >N \}$. What does $n>{}$natural number mean? Is the solution wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Is the answer key wrong?
**Problem**
$$\text{Let $(s_n)$ be a bounded sequence. Prove that $\limsup s_n = \lim _{N \rightarrow \infty} \sup \{s_n: n >N \}$.
}$$

**Answer key**: Since $\{s_n \}$ is bounded, $m= \limsup s_n \in \mathbb{R}$. We need to show (1) $m \le \limsup \{ s_n: n>N \}$, and (2)  $\limsup \{ s_n: n>N \} \le m $.

Proof of (2):
Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s_n<m+ \epsilon$ for all $n>K$ we have $\sup \{ s_n: n> \mathbb{N} \} \le m + \epsilon$. Since this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\sup\{s_n: n>N\} \le m$ whenever $N>K$.

**My question**:  Can someone explain the proof in plain words? In particular,

> we have $\sup \{ s_n: n> \mathbb{N} \} \le m + \epsilon$.

what does it mean to have n larger than natural numbers?

**Original answer below:**
[image: solution]

Comment: Is $n$ a number? How can it be *relate* with the *set* $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: That's not $\mathbb N$.  It's $N$.  $N$ is a large but finite natural number.  In is not $\mathbb N$ the set of natural numbers.

Comment: "$\limsup s_n = \lim _{\color{blue}{N \rightarrow \infty}} sup \{s_n: n >\color{blue}N \}$"   If the answer key *did* write "$\mathbf{\sup \{ s_n: n> \mathbb{N} \} \le m + \epsilon}"$ it was a typo.  They should have written "$\mathbf{\sup \{ s_n: n> \color{blue}{N} \} \le m + \epsilon}$"

Comment: But it isn't true that if for any $\varepsilon >0$ you have $K \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_N \le m+\varepsilon$ then $a_N \le m$ for large $N$. What you can say (since $a_N = \sup \{s_n : n > N\} $ in your case is monotone so the limit exists) is that $\lim a_n \le m$ and only the limit. For example if $a_N = m + \frac{1}{N}$ then you never have $a_N \le m$ but obviously the limit is exactly $m$. It isn't any problem for you, because you are interested only in a limit comparison.

Comment: Just updated image of answer key. It writes $\mathbb{N}$, not $N$.

Comment: @DominikKutek Is the solution wrong?

Comment: So it can make sense to compare a "number" to the set of natural numbers.  BUT, you would have already read about infinite ordinals if that's what they were doing in your book.  Just assume N is an element of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Also, I don't think this question deserves a down vote. It's totally sensible to ask when you're confused about notation.  Perhaps it makes sense add details to the question, about which book this is, etc, so that the answer/comments can help the next person.

Comment: How do you define limsup?

Comment: @JonathanHole Define $\limsup s_n = \sup S$, where $S$ is the set of all subsequential limits of $(s_n)$.

Comment: @JonathanHole Another definition: $\beta$ is the infimum if: there is an integer N so that $x_n < \beta $ for all $n \ge N$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sup\{s_n\,:\, n>\Bbb N\}$ is a misprint. It should be $\sup\{s_n\,:\, n>N\}$.

Comment: Are you sure about it?

Comment: As sure as the random person on the internet can be about a fact which is completely inconsequential to his real life. But yes, I am quite sure.

Comment: @user13985 I hope you're being ironic. Otherwise it mindblows me that you got to this level of "abstraction" allowing to ask something about lim sup WITHOUT understanding basics such as... comparing a set and an integer makes no sense ? It's like you could solve the riemann hypothesis but fail to compute 2+2.